# Как реализовать listener динамически созданных image view?

Tags: android, imageview, setonclicklistener, tag

Как определить какой из динамически созданных `ImageView` был нажат?

Внутри LinearLayout динамически создаются image-view.
Каждому присваивается **setTag()**, также с сервера.
Как я могу реализовать метод **setOnClickListener**, чтобы определить какой из imageview был нажат?
Вот часть кода:

```
for (int i = 0; i < xpp.getAttributeCount(); i++) {
 String value = xpp.getAttributeValue(i);
 value = value.replace("&lt;", "<").replace("&gt;", ">").replace("&quot;", "\"");
 img = new ImageView(CreateClientActivity.this);
 Drawable myDrawable = 
 getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_wallpaper_black_48dp);
 img.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
 img.setTag(value);
 img.setPadding(5, 8, 5, 0);
 linel.addView(img);
 stringArray.add(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы же сами сказали что каждому присваивается setTag().

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getTag()){
        // здесь обратываете клик нажатого imageView
    }
}
```

Comment: да только это и есть уже результат нажатия(callback listener), switch по тегу может помочь определить какой из ImageView был нажат.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei не совсем понял

Comment: @РасулA-ев, не получится, здесь и теги с сервера, предварительно я не могу знать

Comment: @Амирхон можете приложить код

Comment: @РасулA-ев, приложил

Answer (score 0):

Нашел работающий вариант для себя, может кому пригодится:

```
for (int i = 0; i < xpp.getAttributeCount(); i++) {
 String value = xpp.getAttributeValue(i);
 value = value.replace("&lt;", "<").replace("&gt;", ">").replace("&quot;", "\"");
 img = new ImageView(CreateClientActivity.this);
 Drawable myDrawable = 
 getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_wallpaper_black_48dp);
 img.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
 img.setTag(value);
 img.setPadding(5, 8, 5, 0);
     @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
      /////Do some job on button click
    }
 }); 
 linel.addView(img);
 stringArray.add(value);
}
```